# Merging multiple tables to shape using for loop with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have to join multiple tables to a shapefile using a common field. I want to script this in python (i am using ArcGIS 10.1). Below is the script i am using.

I am calling the tables one by one and merging them to the shape. I would like to put this in a for loop so the script reads all the tables (that have prefix dTable) and merge them to the shape.

```
#Redefine the workspace to the geodatabase

env.workspace = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))+'\\'+ out_name +'.gdb'
print "Workspace for GDB:"+ env.workspace

################################################################################
#STEP 5: Start Joining Tables
# Set local variables

featureName = "temp_Streets"
layerName="Streets2"

outFeature = "temp_Streets2"
expression = "temp_Streets.FUNC_CLASS < 99"

################################################################################
# Exclude centriod connectors from the shapefile before joining
try:
     # Make a layer from the feature class
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(featureName,layerName)
    print "Converting to Layer Done !"

    # Select desired features from street layer
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layerName, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
    print "Selection Done !"

    # Copy the layer to a new permanent feature class
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, outFeature)
    print "Copy to new layer Done !"

    print "Step 5: Creating Streets file Done !"
    print "#################################################"
    arcpy.AddMessage("Creating Streets file Done !")
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
################################################################################
joinTable1 = "dTable_HBW_csv"
layername1="j_Streets1"
outFeature1 = "temp_j_Streets1"
joinField = "CONNECT"

# Join the first CSV file
try:
     # Make a layer from the feature class
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outFeature,layername1)
    print "Converting to layername1 Done !"

    # Join the feature layer to a table
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(layername1, joinField, joinTable1, joinField, "KEEP_ALL")
    print "Join 1 Done !"

    # Copy the layer to a new permanent feature class
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layername1, outFeature1)
    print "Copy to new layer 1 Done !"

    print "Step 5a: Joining Streets 1 file Done !"
    print "#################################################"
    arcpy.AddMessage("Joining Streets 1 file Done !")

except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
###############################################################################
joinTable2 = "dTable_HBO_csv"
layername2="j_Streets2"
outFeature2 = "temp_j_Streets2"
joinField2 = joinTable1+"_CONNECT"

# Join Second CSV file
try:
     # Make a layer from the feature class
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outFeature1,layername2)
    print "Converting to layername2 Done !"

    # Join the feature layer to a table
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(layername2, joinField2, joinTable2, joinField, "KEEP_ALL")
    print "Join 2 Done !"

    # Copy the layer to a new permanent feature class
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layername2, outFeature2)
    print "Copy to new layer 2 Done !"

    print "Step 5b: Joining Streets 2 file Done !"
    print "#################################################"
    arcpy.AddMessage("Joining Streets 2 file Done !")

except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to create 4 lists containing the feature dataset names, like so:
You can add to these lists and possibly use [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) to automatically create some of them.

```py
joinTable = ["dTable_HBW_csv", "dTable_HBO_csv"]
layername = ["j_Streets1", "j_Streets2"]
outFeature = ["temp_j_Streets1", "temp_j_Streets2"]
joinField = ["CONNECT", joinTable[0] + "_CONNECT"]
```

From there, you can use the build in `zip()` function to "merge" them together so you're only using 1 for loop.

```py
#Pseudo code..You'll need to play around with this since the output differs from input.
#Possibly consider making an input list as well. Lot's of ways to do stuff in Python.

for table,layer,outFC,field in zip(joinTable, layername, outFeature, joinField):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outFC, layer)
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(layer, field, table, field, "KEEP_ALL")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layer, outFC)
```